# Redirect anything within /attachments/ directory up one level but also removing anything after /attachments/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

WordPress creates an attachment page for any images uploaded through the post editor and "attached" to that post.  After migrating a site, those attachment pages no longer exist, and we now have around 1000 links pointed at 404's.

So, I was looking to find a way to do a redirect for any url that has /attachement/ in it's string and then push that url back up one level (which happens to be the post page). so for instance:

http://mysite.com/2012/news/blog-post-title/attachment/image-page/ (which doesnt exist) will go to 
http://mysite.com/2012/news/blog-post-title/ (which does exist).

Along with redirecting up one level, I also need to remove anything after /attachment/ (in this case the "image-page."

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an extremely simple rewrite; unless there's something missing, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/attachment/?.*$ $1/
```

So some test cases:

```
/2012/news/blog-post-title/attachment/image-page/ -> /2012/news/blog-post-title/
/2012/news/blog-post-title/attachment             -> /2012/news/blog-post-title/
/2012/news/blog-post-title/attachments            -> N/A
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for helping out.  I added that bit of code to the .htaccess file but the redirects are not occuring.  I checked to make sure that the RewriteEngine was On an functioning, and it was.  How would you suggest I further debug.  I work frontend mostly, so I apologize for my ignorance in this.

Comment: You can try [turning on logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and seeing what actions its taking.